# AWS Sagemaker - Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I'm working through some of the example Sagemaker notebooks, and I receive the following Access Denied error when trying to run the `linear_time_series_forecast` example:

```
ValueError: Error training linear-learner-2017-12-21-15-29-34-676: Failed Reason: ClientError: Data download failed:AccessDenied (403): Access Denied
```

I can manually download and upload from my S3 bucket using the AWS command line interface, but the Jupyter notebook fails.

Note that I am running the notebook through Sagemaker's notebook instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this question was also answered on the [AWS Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=270054&tstart=0).

The IAM Role referenced by

> role = get_execution_role()

needs to have a policy attached to it that grants S3:GetObject permission on the S3 bucket holding your training data.

---

Note that as of at least October 28, 2022, the linked forum post now re-directs to a page which states (among other things):

> The thread you are trying to access has outdated guidance, hence we have archived it.

Please keep this in mind as it is possible that this answer no longer works, or that it at some point in the future will no longer work.